# Tab Text in small Caps

Tags: android, tabs

I want small caps in Tabs but its not working. I am using following code for the same. See my emulator image below: -

[image]

The tabs are still in capital letters.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/My.TabText.style"
                    android:background="#f5f5f5"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text"
                    />


    <style name="My.TabText.style" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
            <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
            <item name="android:textColor">#333</item>
            <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Have you tried this parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar.TabText" as parent?

Comment: u are saying parent of "My.TabText.style" right, done that also not working

Comment: no, parent of "MyTabTextStyle", Like this `<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar.TabText">`

Comment: sorry not working!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        style="@style/NavigationTab"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<style name="NavigationTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance</item>
</style>

<style name="NavigationTabTextAppeareance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```